# Multiple Versions of Virtualbox on Yosemite

Tags: virtualbox, osx-yosemite

I am interested in running multiple versions of virtual box on Yosemite for my dev needs as follows:
- (installed) 4.3.30 for running Genymotion Android emulators since there is a bug with newer versions of Virtualbox
- Latest version of Virtualbox for VMs being managed by Vagrant

How can I install and isolate the virtual box instances?